Why do I see a box outlined with my email address in it pointing to the corner of a cell of my Excel spreadsheet? What is it? How do I get rid of it?
In Excel 2010, my spreedsheet has automatically produced a box with my email address in it and pointing to a SUM(Name) cell.
What is that? How can I remove it?


Automatically added? You mean Excel added your email address itself? I find that hard to believe, though perhaps I am misunderstanding you. Please EDIT your post to make it more clear. Give us at least a mockup of the data and a better description of what has happened, what it was like before, what changed, what you expect, etc.

Based on your edit that's just a Track Changes tag indicating that you made a change. Check your Track Changes settings on this file.

It may be good to blur your mail address there.

I agree with Hannu, it may be a note box, you may delete it.

Right click that cell with the red upper right corner...
Select Delete Comment or Delete Note in the popup menu - it might be either of them.

